# Searching with constant argument in Lucene

Tags: java, search, lucene

I have problem with searching. I have 5 indexed fields in my database table. For example

1. `profession`
2. `educated profession`
3. `name_surname`
4. `age`
5. `description`

I want to search first for `profession`. When I have profession. I want use this profession and find for example 1. Profession: baker. After that I want search for `educated profession`. So if I search e.g. for "mason" after that, I want get list:

```
1. baker 2. mason 3. ..... 4. ..... 5. .....
1. baker 2. mason 3. ..... 4. ..... 5. .....
1. baker 2. mason 3. ..... 4. ..... 5. .....
1. baker 2. mason 3. ..... 4. ..... 5. .....
```

But when searching for 2 `educated profession`s I want to search only for people who have profession "baker" (this must be searchable too).

Is there any way to do this in Lucene, as I'd select from database like this:

```sql
select educated_profession from table
where profession='baker'
and educated profession='mason'
```

I used a simplified example so it was easier way to explain what I meant.

I could do select list or something like that but in database I have over 100k "professions" and 150k "educated professions".

Comment: Proper basic formatting, proper grammar/spelling, and proper markdown help a lot with a question. Without it folks will likely not answer or perhaps even downvote. Don't forget to use the preview and perfect a question before asking, as most views occur after first posting it.

Comment: Yes there is a way. Now try doing it and come back when you have a specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, check out the [*query syntax documentation*](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#AND).  Either this:

```
+profession:baker +educated_profession:mason
```

Or this:

```
profession:baker AND educated_profession:mason
```

Though I've [never much cared for the latter](https://lucidworks.com/blog/why-not-and-or-and-not/) (to be clear, I'm not the author of that article, but I do agree whole-heartedly).